# React Warning: How do I locate the bad setState() call inside my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting a warning in my browser when I am trying to set the state of my context provider. The warning in the browser console is:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`DataContextProvider`) while rendering a different component (`PastLeaveReqUpperLinks`).
```

How do I go about finding this? I think I need to apply useEffect() hooks to my set methods, but when I try, it says I cannot use a hook inside a callback.

My code is below - I think the issue lies within the modal (commented with MODAL START) - notably the setUnderlayShow() and modalOnOff() set functions that set the state of the context provider.

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { DataContext } from '../../contexts/DataContext';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../../styles/leaveRequests.css';

import loader from '../../img/unitIcons/loader.svg';
import tick from '../../img/unitIcons/tick.svg';
import cross from '../../img/unitIcons/cross.svg';
import close from '../../img/modals/close.svg';

import '../../styles/modals.css';

const PastLeaveRequestsUnits = () => {
  
  const {
    underlayShow,
    setUnderlayShow,
    modalState,
    modalOnOff,
    requests,
  } = useContext(DataContext);

  // - - - - - M O D A L - S T A R T - - - - -

  // modalOnOff is a fct in the DataContext which turns modal on/off
  // is it also used in LeaveReqsPage.js for the underlay element
  // modal: store selected unit for modal to use to determine which data
  let [selectedUnit, setSelectedUnit] = useState('');
  let updateSelectedUnit = (item) => {
    setSelectedUnit(item);
  };

  // modal - open: fct to update the modalState and update selected unit
  const openModal = (item) => {
    updateSelectedUnit(item);
    modalOnOff();
    // uses DataContext's underlay state
    setUnderlayShow(!underlayShow);
  };

  // modal - close: fct to update the modalState and update selected unit
  const closeModal = (item) => {
    updateSelectedUnit(item);
    modalOnOff();
    setUnderlayShow(!underlayShow);
  };
  // - - - - - M O D A L - E N D - - - - -



  // COMBINE ALL LEAVE TYPES
  // map through all requests and store each request into a new array
  let allRequests = [];

  if (requests.annualLeave) {
    requests.annualLeave.forEach((item) => {
      allRequests.push(item);
    });
  }

  if (requests.tilRequest) {
    requests.tilRequest.forEach((item) => {
      allRequests.push(item);
    });
  }

  if (requests.customReq) {
    requests.customReq.forEach((item) => {
      allRequests.push(item);
    });
  }

  // sort requests array by startdate
  var sortedRequests = allRequests.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.start == b.start ? 0 : +(a.start > b.start) || -1;
  });

  // Mapper: map through leave units
  const getLeaveUnits = sortedRequests.map((item) => {
    // determine unit colour
    let unitColour = '';
    if (item.approved === null) {
      unitColour = 'unit reqPending';
    } else if (item.approved === true) {
      unitColour = 'unit reqApproved';
    } else if (item.approved === false) {
      unitColour = 'unit reqDeclined';
    }

    // determine status icon
    let statusIcon = loader;
    if (item.approved === null) {
      statusIcon = loader;
    } else if (item.approved === true) {
      statusIcon = tick;
    } else {
      statusIcon = cross;
    }

    // determine leave type name
    let leaveTypeName = '';
    if (item.type === 'annualLeave') {
      leaveTypeName = 'Annual Leave';
    } else if (item.type === 'tilRequest') {
      leaveTypeName = 'Time in Lieu';
    } else {
      leaveTypeName = item.type;
    }

    // rounder fct for use in convertTimestamp()
    const rounder = (num, rounder) => {
      var multiplier = 1 / rounder;
      return Math.round(num * multiplier) / multiplier;
    };

    // convert timestamp
    const convertTimestamp = (timestamp, type) => {
      let days = timestamp / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
      // for A/L leave types
      if (type === 'annualLeave') {
        let value = rounder(days, 0.5);
        let d = 'days';

        if (value === 1) {
          d = 'day';
        }

        if (value < 0.5) {
          return `0.5 days`;
        } else {
          return `${value} ${d}`;
        }
        // for til leave types
      } else if (type === 'tilRequest') {
        let mins = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000 / 60);
        if (mins > 59) {
          let hours = Math.floor(mins / 60);
          let modul = mins % (hours * 60);
          if (modul > 0) {
            return `${hours}h ${modul}m`;
          } else {
            return `${hours}h`;
          }
        } else {
          return `${mins} mins`;
        }
      } else {
        let days = timestamp / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

        let value = rounder(days, 0.5);
        let d = 'days';

        if (value === 1) {
          d = 'day';
        }

        if (value < 0.5) {
          return `0.5 days`;
        } else {
          return `${value} ${d}`;
        }
      }
    };

    // start & end date formatter
    const startEndDate = (start, end) => {
     
// removed irrelevant code

      return `${startDay} ${startMonth} ${startYr} ${divider} ${endDay} ${endMonth} ${endYr}`;
    };

    // if unit is older than today, show
    // today as a timestamp
    let today = Math.round(new Date().getTime());

    // if modal open, scroll-lock the requests container
    // if (modalState) {
    //   $('.innerUnitsContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    // } else {
    //   $('.innerUnitsContainer').css('overflow', 'auto');
    // }

    // modal: template
    const modal = () => {
      let status = '';

      // need to make a function to return name of manager
      let manager = 'Sean Wheldon';

      let submitDate = () => {
        let dateObj = new Date(selectedUnit.submitDate);
        let day = dateObj.toLocaleString('en-US', { day: 'numeric' });
        let month = dateObj.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'short' });
        return `${day} ${month}`;
      };

      if (selectedUnit.approved === true) {
        status = `Approved by ${manager}`;
      } else if (selectedUnit.approved === null) {
        status = `Submitted on ${submitDate()}`;
      } else if (selectedUnit.approved === false) {
        status = `Declined by ${manager}`;
      }

      let editButton = () => {
        if (selectedUnit.approved !== false) {
          return <p className='editButton'>EDIT REQUEST</p>;
        }
      };

      return (
        <div>
          <img
            src={close}
            className='closeBtn'
            onClick={closeModal}
            alt='Close'
          />
          <p className='modalTitle'>
            {startEndDate(selectedUnit.start, selectedUnit.end)}
          </p>
          <p className='requestStatus'>{status}</p>
          <div onClick={closeModal}>{editButton()}</div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    if (item.end <= today && item.approved !== false) {
      return (
        <div
          className={unitColour}
          key={item.reqID}
          onClick={() => {
            openModal(item);
          }}
        >
          <div className='unitLeft'>
            <img src={statusIcon} alt='Status Icon' id='statusIcon' />
          </div>

          <div className='unitMiddle'>
            <p id='unitLeaveType'>{leaveTypeName}</p>
            <p id='unitDate'>{startEndDate(item.start, item.end)}</p>
          </div>

          <div className='unitDivider'></div>

          <div className='unitRight'>
            <p id='unitDuration'>
              {convertTimestamp(item.duration, item.type)}
            </p>
          </div>
          {/* M O D A L */}

          <div
            className={`modalBackground ${!!modalState ? 'open' : ''}`}
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
            }}
          >
            {modal()}
          </div>
          {/*  E N D    M O D A L */}
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  // render
  return <div className='requestsContainer'>{getLeaveUnits}</div>;
};

export default PastLeaveRequestsUnits;
```